# Lag in AutocompleteTextView from Sqlite Database having over million records

Tags: android, sqlite

I am fetching records into adapter using `addTextChangedListener`. If I query through database asynchronously, then there is no lag but I am not getting suggestions in my `AutocompleteTextView` as soon as I enter the word and if I query on UI thread then there is a serious lag. I already indexed my table.
How can I improve my `sqlite` database performance.

**Query**

```
    String where =x+" LIKE ?";
    String[] whereArgs = new String[] {column_name+"%"};
    cursor = db.query(TABLE_NAME,TABLE_COLUMNS,where,whereArgs, null, null, null, "10");
```

**Asynctask**

```
private class FindText extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void>
{
    private ArrayList<TextModel> textModels;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        startSppiner("", "", false);
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
        textModel= new StoreFactory(mActivity, 0).getSchedulesByWordSpecific(params[0].trim());
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        stopSppiner();
        for(TextModel textModel: textModels)
            {
                mAdapter.add(textModel.getWord());  
                textMap.put(textModel.getText(), textModel);
            }
        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

}
```

Comment: Some more info on how your database is done, and how you do the querying would help.

Comment: Post the async code. database calls on UI thread is BAD practice